# NSInternalInconsistencyException Error in constraints

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I am getting this error

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.'

I am trying to show a view on click of a button and have added the constraints on the click function of the button but when ever I am hitting the button am getting this error, this error was not coming earlier don't why all of a sudden it start coming .
Please find the code snippet below:

```
self.view.addConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: datePickerView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 250),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: datePickerView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: datePickerView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: sender, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: datePickerView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: sender, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            ])
```

Any suggestions how can it be solved.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you reviewed [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Impossible+to+set+up+layout+with+view+hierarchy+unprepared+for+constraint) on the error?

Comment: @ranbijay : Those constraints does not make any sense logically hence the error. You are applying height constraint and width constraint on datePickerView then why are u adding those constraints to view's constraints array ? What has self.view got anything to with date picker's height or width constraint? You specify that date picker should be horizontally and vertically center to sender which is button, so constraint is between picker n button. What is self.view got to do with those constraints? Read about constraints n how to apply them all have ur problem solved